# The letter ü is not shown correctly

Tags: gnome, 16.04, fonts, internationalization

For some time now, words with the letter `ü` aren't shown correctly anymore for me with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

[image: ü in Chrome]

In this picture, you can see that the cursor after typing `ü` is **in front of(!)** the `ü`. When I type the next character, it'll overwrite the `ü`. This is in Chrome.

[image: ü in Firefox]

This picture is from Firefox. As you can see, the words "dürfen" and "für" aren't shown correctly.

It all started "all of a sudden". Don't remember when and how.

What's going on there?

Comment: Is there the same problem when you login with openbox?

Answer (score 2):

This might be [bug 1592833](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1592833) where accented characters are not being displayed right with Ubuntu GNOME's default [Cantarell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantarell_(typeface)) font.

Comment: So downloading and installing [fonts-cantarell_0.0.24-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/fonts-cantarell_0.0.24-1_all.deb) may fix the issue. But if it does, and if Cantarell is default font in Ubuntu GNOME, isn't this an important enough issue to be fixed in 16.04? (Just nominated the bug for Xenial.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes. I intend to work on an [SRU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) for it this week. Thank you for helping triage the bug.